# Joomla articles do not work on making it SEO friendly

Tags: configuration, seo, joomla1.7

I have installed my joomla website in a sub-folder,
i moved it to my root. I changed the config file and did the needful. Everything is working great.
Now when I select

```
*SEO Settings > Search Engine Friendly URLs*
```

My website inside pages do not work.
What is the problem?
When I put it off everything works great. But you can understand how important it is for my website to have a Search Engine Friendly URl. Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to rename htaccess.txt to .htaccess

What changes did you make to the config? Joomla uses relative URLs so you shouldn't have to make any changes when moving a site from a subdirectory to the root. I do it all the time, as recently as last night.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Brent, I am able to login to my joomla website without any problem from root, even my website is working great.... The problem occurs only when i set "SEO Settings > Search Engine Friendly URLs" - Inside pages do not work...

Comment: What is the error and did you rename htaccess.txt? A link would be helpful.